# Can't remux MP4 into MP4 with FFmpeg (Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, muxer

I'm trying to create a copy of an MP4 with all streams (and metadata) except video.

However, for some reason, I get a codec error even though both input and output are mp4.

I've tried mapping everything, but with `-vn`:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -copy_unknown -map 0 -c copy out.mp4`

Or with negative mapping:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:v -c copy out.mp4`

Both commands return:
`[mp4 @ 0000012b16bce340] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container`

Any ideas?

How is it possible that there are codec errors when trying to remux MP4 into MP4?

You can download the video I tried this on here: https://icedrive.net/0/e4EpBXLe2V

Log: https://pastebin.com/5gD70KXn

Comment: Need to see the complete log from your command.

Comment: Log: https://pastebin.com/5gD70KXn

Comment: If you don't need the tmcd data then add `-map -0:d`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Will this strip anything other than timecodes?

Comment: It will strip all data streams. In this case just the problematic `Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the data stream(s) with a negative map:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:d -c copy out.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).